# Cash on delivery (COD) based on user role and product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, user-roles

I need to customize cash on delivery (COD) in WooCommerce based on user role and product category.

Requirements:

- By default COD is hidden
- COD is visible when a product in cart, belongs to a certain category (category 1)
- Users who have the role "x" must always see COD, even if they don't have category 1 products in the cart.

This is my code attempt to meet the above requirements:

```
function disable_cod($available_gateways)
{

    if (is_admin()) return $available_gateways;

    $role = false;
     //check whether the avaiable payment gateways have Cash on delivery and user is not logged in or he is a user with role customer
    if (isset($available_gateways['cod']) && (current_user_can('customer') || !is_user_logged_in()))
    {
        $role = true;
    }

    foreach (WC()
        ->cart
        ->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item)
    {
        $prod_simple = true;
        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        // Get the product types in cart (example)
        if ($product->is_product_category('X')) $prod_simple = false;

    }

    if ($prod_simple = $role = true) unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
    

    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_cod', 99, 1);
```

I definitely got something wrong in the syntax, but I hope the logical concept is correct? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains some minor mistakes:

- `is_product_category()` is a conditional tag which returns true when viewing a product category archive. Use [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) instead.
- Loop through the cart is only necessary when the user role is not fulfilled.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Not on admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;

    // Initialize: flag - default true
    $flag = true;

    // Has certain user role
    if ( current_user_can( 'certain-user-role' ) ) {
        // False
        $flag = false;
    } else {
        // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
        $categories = array( 63, 15, 'categorie-1' );

        // Isset
        if ( WC()->cart ) {
            // Loop through cart items
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                // Has term (product category)
                if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
                    // False, break loop
                    $flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        // Cod
        if ( isset( $payment_gateways['cod'] ) ) {
            // Remove
            unset( $payment_gateways['cod'] );
        }  
    }
    
    return $payment_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for a specific role, add this to your function.php:

```
function custom_enable_cod_for_shop_manager( $available_gateways ) {

// Check if the user is a shop_manager
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    // Enable Cash on Delivery for shop_manager
    $available_gateways['cod'] = new WC_Gateway_COD();
}

return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','custom_enable_cod_for_shop_manager' );
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**